# return list after Join two list from method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, return-value

```
public List<Employee> CallSupportFindAll()
{
List<Employee> list1 = new List<Employee>();
list1 .Add(new Employee { Name = "Emp_1", BasicSalary = 1000, Id = Guid.NewGuid(), HRA = 100, DA = 10});
list1 .Add(new Employee { Name = "Emp_2", BasicSalary = 1000 * 2, Id = Guid.NewGuid(), HRA = 200, DA = 20});
list1 .Add(new Employee { Name = "Emp_3", BasicSalary = 1000 * 3, Id = Guid.NewGuid(), HRA = 300, DA = 30});

List<Employee> list2= new List<Employee>();
list2.Add(new Employee { Name = "Emp_1", TotalSalary = 1110 });
list2.Add(new Employee { Name = "Emp_2", TotalSalary = 2220 });
list2.Add(new Employee { Name = "Emp_3", TotalSalary = 3330 });

var Query = (from emp1 in list1
    join emp2 in list2
    on new { emp1.Name }
    equals new { emp2.Name }
    select new
    {
        emp1.Name,
        emp1.Id,
        emp1.BasicSalary,
        emp1.HRA,
        emp1.DA,
        emp2.TotalSalary
        }).ToList();
return Query.toList();
```

This Give me error at line `return Query.ToList()` --cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collection.generic.List<Anonymous Type#1>` to `System.Collection.generic.List<Employee>`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return `anonymous` type instead of `List<Employee>`.

Do this instead:-

```
select new Employee
                  {
                     Name = emp1.Name,
                     Id = emp1.Id,
                     BasicSalary = emp1.BasicSalary,
                     HRA = emp1.HRA,
                     DA = emp1.DA,
                     TotalSalary = emp2.TotalSalary
                  });
return Query.ToList();
```

Alos, you don't need `ToList` at two places, either use it in query or with return type as I did.